# spring security which class to override to get the wrong password

Tags: spring-security

In spring security 3.0.5.RELEASE, which class and method can I override to catch the BadCredentialsException for wrong password. Here is a snippet of my security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDao"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</beans:bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref='daoAuthenticationProvider'/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler and override onAuthenticationFailure().  It gets an exception passed to it.  exception.getAuthentication().getCredentials() will return the password that was tried.

Configure your AuthenticationFailureHandler in the form-login element:

```
<form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
```